# Profile with "Subscribe to Dashboards" checkbox still dont have the schedule option

Tags: reporting, dashboard, schedule

I need to give a specific user to schedule a dashboard and have given the the access through profile system permissions but the targeted user still dont have the option.

[image]

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the user has all the required permission but you need to look into these notes, considerations, and limitations:

1. Each user can set up subscriptions for up to 5 dashboards.
2. You can subscribe to filtered dashboards, but dashboard filters are
   never applied to emailed dashboards. When you open the email, the
   dashboard is displayed unfiltered.
3. Dashboard subscription emails don't reflect changes made to color
   palette and theme.
4. Dashboards that are configured to display data as The dashboard
   viewer under View Dashboard As settings in Dashboard Properties
   don’t support subscriptions. You can’t subscribe to them.
5. In the email to subscribers, the ‘From’ address is taken from My
   Email Settings. If no address is specified in My Email settings, the
   ‘From’ address is taken from the User object.